# Are these continued fractions of integrals known?

Tags: integration, reference-request, maxima-minima, continued-fractions

<sub>Crossposted on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448408/are-these-continued-fractions-of-integrals-known)</sub>

Motivated by [Bowman and McLaughlin (2000)](https://digitalcommons.wcupa.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1039&context=math_facpub) on polynomial continued fractions, I considered an extension to functional continued fractions, where the numerator of each fraction is the integral of the previous fraction.

That is, define the **continued fraction integral transform (CFIT)** as \begin{align}\{\mathcal If(t)\}(s)=\dfrac{f(s)}{1+\dfrac{\int_0^s f(x)\,dx}{1+\dfrac{\int_0^s\int_0^u f(x)\,dx\,du}{1+\cdots}}}=\dfrac{f(s)}{1+\dfrac{f^{(-1)}(s)}{1+\dfrac{f^{(-2)}(s)}{1+\cdots}}}={\large{\mathop{\mathrm{K}}_{n=0}^{\infty}}}\frac{f^{(-n)}(s)}1\end{align} where $f\in C^\infty(\Bbb R)$ and $f^{(-k)}$ is Lagrange's notation for the $k$th antiderivative of $f$.

Some elementary properties of the transform include

1. $\{\mathcal I(0)\}(s)=0$;
2. $\{\mathcal If\}(0)=f(0)$;
3. $\{\mathcal If\}(s)=\dfrac{f'(s)}{\{\mathcal If'\}(s)}-1$ for all non-constant $f$ such that $f(0)=0$.

Considering the simplest, non-trivial case $f(t)\equiv1$, we have $f^{(-k)}(t)=t^k/k!$ so that $$\{\mathcal I(1)\}(s)=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac s{1+\dfrac{s^2/2!}{1+\cdots}}}.$$ [image]

We can see that as $n$ increases, $\mathcal I(1)$ produces more waves. As @PeterForeman mentioned in the comments, the limit $\lim\limits_{s\to-\infty}\mathcal I(1)$ does not exist since it is zero for odd $n$ and $+1$ for even $n$. However, I believe there are more things that can be investigated.

> **Questions**
>
> 1. Has the CFIT already been studied/discovered? If so, reference to literature would be appreciated.
> 2. Going back to the example of $\{\mathcal I(1)\}(s)$, is it true that the maximum value of each wave increases as $s$ increases up to the first wave? Are there an infinite number of such waves, and is there a closed form for $\max\mathcal I(1)$?
> 3. The period of the oscillations of $\mathcal I(1)$ appears to converge to $$\dfrac4e=1.4715\cdots$$ Can this be proven?

Empirically, the argmins are

```
-2.12897, -3.73409, -5.26940, -6.78494, -8.29119, -9.79168, -11.2881, -12.7814, -14.2723,
-15.7613, -17.2487, -18.7348, -20.2198, -21.7038, -23.1870, -24.6695, -26.1513, -27.6326,
-29.1133, -30.5937, -32.0736, -33.5531, -35.0323, -36.5111, -37.9897, -39.4680, -40.9461,
-42.4239, -43.9015, -45.3790, -46.8562, -48.3332, -49.8101, -51.2869, -52.7635, -54.2399,
-55.7162, -57.1924, -58.6685, -60.1445, -61.6203, -63.0961, -64.5717, -66.0473, -67.5228,
...
```

with consecutive differences

```
         1.60512, 1.53531, 1.51554, 1.50625, 1.50049, 1.49642, 1.49330, 1.49090, 
1.48900, 1.48740, 1.48610, 1.48500, 1.48400, 1.48320, 1.48250, 1.48180, 1.48130, 
1.48070, 1.48040, 1.47990, 1.47950, 1.47920, 1.47880, 1.47860, 1.47830, 1.47810, 
1.47780, 1.47760, 1.47750, 1.47720, 1.47700, 1.47690, 1.47680, 1.47660, 1.47640, 
1.47630, 1.47620, 1.47610, 1.47600, 1.47580, 1.47580, 1.47560, 1.47560, 1.47550, ...
```

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Also $\lim_{s\to-\infty}I(1)$ clearly does not exist as it equals $0$ for any odd number of terms in an approximation and $1$ for any even number.

Comment: For $3.$, does one need $f(0) = 0$ since $\int_0^s f'(x) dx = f(x) - f(0)$?

Comment: @StephenHarrison Correct, edited. This would perfectly align with the previous property, substituting $s=0$ and using $2.$ gives $f(0)=\frac{f'(0)}{f'(0)}-1$.

Comment: It isn't completely clear to me why taking $\lim_{s \rightarrow -\infty} \sum_{k=0}^N$ for $N$ even/odd implies the limit doesn't exist for $N= \infty$. It seems like commutation of limits.

Answer (score 5):

Not an answer, but one more picture, with the functions for 100 and 150 terms superposed.

[image]

It is not clear what is happening on the left.

**EDIT:**

Here is the code (using sagemath):

```
def fun(x, N=150):
    L = [x**k/gamma(k + 1) for k in range(N, -1, -1)]
    resu = 1.0
    for t in L:
        resu = t / (1 + resu)
    return resu
P1 = plot(lambda x:fun(x, 100),-12, 3, aspect_ratio=1, color='red'); P1
```

Answer (score 2):

For your question:

> 1. Has the CFIT already been studied/discovered? If so, reference to literature would be appreciated.

I am not sure, but surprisingly, your example of
$\{\mathcal I(1)\}(s)$ appears in the entry of
[OEIS sequence A319173](http://oeis.org/A319173)

`Expansion of e.g.f. 1/(1 + x/(1 + (x^2/2!)/(1 + (x^3/3!)/(1 + (x^4/4!)/(1 + ...))))), a continued fraction`

This sequence was authored on Sep 12, 2018 by Ilya Gutkovskiy.
Unfortunately, there is no other relevant information there yet.